# DOM Lag while inputing (over 80 or 100+ component in one template and every component has a watcher )

Tags: vue.js

I have a problem for this every time i input, checking box, or selecting radio. the dom is lagging or delay response.

every component has this kind of code.

```
<template>
    <div>
       ..some temp ex.
       <input v-model="someData.name"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex"
export default ({
  data: () => ({
       someData: {}
  }),
  watch:{
      someData:{
        handler(obj){
         this.putDataToVuex({ someData: obj })  
       }
     }
  },
  methods:{
     ...mapActions(`vuexname`,["putDataToVuex"])
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Does your code work when using 10 or less components?

Comment: @JeroenHeier yes its work and run smooth. this is my first time i encounter this.the last project i did has only 30 component in one template but it's run smooth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No wonder, you have 100+ store subs. This is not okay

Comment: hehehe.. it's complicated, but need to separated per module . :(

Comment: Connect store with parent container component, then pass data to this childrens using props

Comment: ahehe. well im using that sir.

Comment: You need to change architecture of your app. Create container component, that connected to the store. Then pass this data down to your checkbox with props.